# How do I bind FontSize for WPF TextBox in XAML to a class member variable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I bind FontSize for WPF TextBox in XAML to a class member variable?

I have a collection of fonts that I use through the application.
I would like to change the values of those fonts dynamically in my code behind and then have the changes reflected during runtime.

How do I achieve this?

**Here is what my class definition looks like**

```
public ClassFoo
{
   public double FontSize {get; set;}
}
```

This is how I define my class in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public ClassFoo SampleClass;
```

**Here is my what my XAML looks like:**

```
<TextBlock Name="txtSample" Text="SomeText" 
     FontSize="{Binding SampleClass.FontSize}"/>
```

**Then at runtime, I instantiate the class and initialize it:**

```
SampleClass = new ClassFoo()
{
   FontSize = 16;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would create it like that:

```
 public class MainWindow : Page
    {
        public Foo Foo { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
        }
    }


    public class Foo : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private double _fontSize;

        public double FontSize
        {
            get { return _fontSize; }
            set
            {
                _fontSize = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FontSize));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

and then call it like:

```
<TextBlock Name="txtSample" Text="SomeText" 
     FontSize="{Binding Foo.FontSize}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need a DataContext = this; in your constructor for Mainwindow.xaml.cs.  You also need in Mainwindow.xaml.cs that returns SampleClass.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind to *public properties* so the first thing to do would be to make `SampleClass` a property:

```
public ClassFoo SampleClass { get; set; }
```

And if you intend to set it dynamically at runtime after the constructor of the window has returned, the window should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and raise change notfications for the taget property to get automatically updated.

Finally the source of the binding must be set to the window somehow. You could set the `Source` property of the binding explicitly or set the `DataContext` of the `TextBlock` or any of its parent element to an instance of the window.

Try this implementation of the `MainWindow` class together with the XAML markup you posted:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SampleClass = new ClassFoo()
        {
            FontSize = 16
        };
    }

    private ClassFoo _sampleClass;
    public ClassFoo SampleClass
    {
        get { return _sampleClass; }
        set { _sampleClass = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```